# How we can get the data from the table by limiting the number of identical columns MySql

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

Yesterday I tried to retrieve data from my db table using 'user_id' as a criterion to limit the amount of data per user.

I tried to get data from table https://prnt.sc/p53zhp in format like this https://prnt.sc/p541wk and limit the number of output records for user_id where limit will be 2 (count(user_id) <= 2), but i don't understand how to do that. What kind of sql request can i use to get this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: doesnot work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your RDBMS, here is a solution yo select only the top 2 records per user. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to rank records by `id` within groups of records having the same `user_id`, and the filter out unerelevant records in the outer query, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id)
    FROM mytable
) x WHERE rn <= 2
```

---

On earlier versions of MySQL, you could use self-`LEFT JOIN` the table and use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(...) < 2` to limit the results to first two records per group:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.user_id, 
    t.vip, 
    t.title,
    t.description,
    t.data 
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable t1 ON t1.user_id = t.user_id AND t1.id > t.id
GROUP BY
    t.id, 
    t.user_id, 
    t.vip, 
    t.title,
    t.description,
    t.data 
HAVING COUNT(t1.id) < 2
```

Comment: i am using old mysql, without partition by

Comment: @MykhailoK: then you might want to have a look at the link that was flagged as a duplicate of your question, which provides solutions for older versions of MySQL.

Comment: doesnot work form me, i can understand this sql query

Comment: @MykhailoK: I updated my answer with a query for MySQL < 8.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if your problem is a Transact-SQL or your code.

In SQL you can limit record with "LIMIT": https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

In code, you can use a condition IF.

Comment: I want use only sql request, without if in php code

Comment: In SQL: SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,2 for exract latest 2 result. You can increse a SQL, with where clause. Ex: SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 2 LIMIT 0,2

Comment: I want to select no more than two records for each user